# Execel duplicates based on two criteria

Tags: excel, duplicates, repeat

How can I use excel to find repeat guests based on over 400 houses, but unique to that house.

Example

```
House A Customer A    
House A Customer A     
House A Customer B    
House A Customer B    
House B Customer A     
House B Customer B    
House B Customer B
```

I want to find how mnay repeat people there are to House A only, House B only etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the function countifs() like this:

[image]

I have assumed House X is in column A and Customer X in column B...

Answer (score 0):

A pivot Table will do it.  Put customer in both the rows and values:

[image]

Or if you want it the other way, put house in the value and change the order:

[image]

Comment: Is it easily scallable for 30000 records / 400 properties?

Comment: Then put House in the values instead of customer